# How to get a detailed breakdown of the kernel execution time of my program?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, profiling

I have a program that performs some AI inference task.

With the `time(1)` command, I find that it spent a fair amount of time in the kernel (i.e. the `system` time as outputted by `time(1)`).

Is there a way to find a more detailed breakdown of this time? For example, how much time spent on syscalls, context-switches, I/O interactions and such.

Comment: `man perf` this is what you need. On some CPUs you will get even better coverage because they have a hardware support for (branch) tracing.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best approach would be to profile the source code, for example if this is a python program you're running you could use cProfile.

If you don't have access to the source code or you are only interested in syscalls, you could try to use [strace (1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace).

To print a summary of the time spent on each syscall use the `-c` flag :

```
$ strace -c -f ls
some random files
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 31.91    0.000150           6        27           mmap
 17.02    0.000080           4        18           mprotect
 15.74    0.000074           7        10           open
  8.09    0.000038           3        11           fstat
  7.66    0.000036           5         8           read
  6.60    0.000031           2        13           close
  2.77    0.000013          13         1           write
  2.77    0.000013          13         1           openat
  2.55    0.000012           6         2           getdents
  2.34    0.000011           6         2         1 access
  1.70    0.000008           4         2           munmap
  0.43    0.000002           1         2           ioctl
  0.43    0.000002           2         1           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           stat
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           statfs
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000470                   111         1 total
```

If you want to know precisely how much time is spent on each syscall, you can use the `-T` flag (time is on the right) :

```
$ strace -T -f ls
execve("/usr/bin/ls", ["ls"], [/* 49 vars */]) = 0 <0.000183>
brk(NULL)                               = 0x2066000 <0.000016>
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7fbe67d000 <0.000012>
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000011>
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000012>
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=121028, ...}) = 0 <0.000011>
mmap(NULL, 121028, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7fbe65f000 <0.000010>
close(3)                                = 0 <0.000006>
open("/lib64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000014>

[...]
```

From the man page :

```
 -f          Trace child processes as they are created by currently  traced  processes
                   as  a  result  of  the fork(2), vfork(2) and clone(2) system calls.
```

```
 -c          Count time, calls, and errors for each system call and report  a  summary
                   on  program  exit.
```

```
-T          Show  the  time  spent in system calls.  This records the time difference
                   between the beginning and the end of each system call.
```